# Microsoft security update KB2656351 prevents output caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, cookies

I am working with .Net framework 4 and cookies are used in my application. Due to Microsoft security update KB2656351, output caching does not work. I can not remove cookies. If I remove the above update, caching works fine.

Please give me a workaround to use output caching while using cookies and without removing the update. (Asking the client to uninstall this update from their servers is not an option.)

Comment: This question probably belongs to superuser section on SO. But perhaps this will help: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/astebner/archive/2005/04/08/406671.aspx

Comment: Is there any way to forward this to superuser section?

Comment: I think only the moderators can migrate the question or perhaps when there are enough close votes for migration.